# Issue with autoreleasing NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am unable to release NSMutableArray that I created in a method.

```
SqliteData *s = [SqliteData alloc];

items = [NSArray alloc];
items = [s getItems:parent];
[s release];
```

IN SQLITeDATA class

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getItems:(NSString *)parent
{
    NSMutableArray *items = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
    return items
}
```

The app crashes, if I remove the autorelease it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct version is :

```
SqliteData *s = [[SqliteData alloc] init];
items = [[s getItems:parent] retain];
[s release];
```

Which is similar, but less optimized, to :

```
SqliteData *s = [[[SqliteData alloc] init] autorelease];
items = [[s getItems:parent] retain];
```

---

Beware about memory leaks :

```
SqliteData *s = [SqliteData alloc];
items = [NSArray alloc]; // memory leak there!
items = [s getItems:parent];
[s release];
```

You are leaking memory, since your replace newly allocated `items` address with another.

And `alloc` without `init` is a non-sense. *(you are allocating memory, but not initialized it!)*

Answer (score 2):

- You're overwriting first `items` with a different value on next line. You don't need that `alloc` first — it does nothing.
- It's invalid to use `alloc` without `init`. Use `[[foo alloc] init]` or `[foo new]`.
- Autoreleased objects are only temporary (until end of life of current pool, which is usually life of thread or callback — don't expect object will survive much longer than duration of function it's in). You need to `retain` them.